# If a diffusion is Gaussian, what does it imply to its drift and volatility?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $(Y_t)$ be a stochastic process solution to the SDE
$$dY_t= \lambda(Y_t,t) dt + \sigma(Y_t,t) dB_t. $$

If we know that $(Y_t)$ is a Gaussian process, what does it inform us on the drift $\lambda$ and the volatility $\sigma$ ? To my knowledge, the only link between the distribution of $(Y_t)$ and its drift/volatility is Fokker-Planck equation: if $p(x,t)$ is the density function of $(Y_t)$, we have

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} p(x, t)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[\lambda(x, t) p(x, t)]+\frac 1 2 \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}[\sigma^{2}\left(x, t\right)p(x, t)]$$

I tried "brut-forcing" by plugging in a Gaussian density in the PDE and try to see what contraints on the drift and volatility we get, without much success.

EDIT: you can assume $(Y_t)$ to be one-dimensional for simplicity, but a general answer would be more than welcome.

Comment: Are you considering the one-dimensional case here? The answer will be that the drift and diffusion have to be deterministic (i.e., functions of $t$ only).

Comment: @user159517 This is not true. For example the standard Brownian bridge on $(0,1)$ is Gaussian and is the solution to $-Y_t/(1-t) dt+  dB_t$

Comment: Good point. I even had a rough argument for that, will have to figure out where it goes wrong.

Comment: For a n-dimensional process, If $\lambda(y, t)$ is affine, $\lambda(y, t) = f(t) + g(t)y$, and $\sigma(y, t)$ does not depend on y,  then $Y_t$ will be Gaussian.